# Can't adjust ImageView on Android API below 16

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, adjustment

I want to set a background image in my app, which will fill all screen and scale if needed, so I set it in my main_layout.xml like that:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_iphone_6_plus" />
```

and it looks like this
[image: api >= 16]

not very good, I need this picture to adjust in width too, actually.

ok, so this works in most cases and with all API's higher 16, but when I run my app on api lower 16 ( minTargetSdk=14 ), I see this:

[image]

I have no idea why it shows like that, I have already tried this [tutorial](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/correct-imageview-adjustviewbounds-with-adjustable-imageview/en), and replaced ImageView with com.inthecheesefactory.thecheeselibrary.widget.AdjustableImageView

but it didn't change anything at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your background image is only this gray picture with gradient in the middle, then move the drawable to `android:background` **to parent container**. You don't need additional `ImageView` for that.

But, if you want to set bitmap as background and keep ratio of this image on different devices and orientations, you should use `ImageView` and its `android:scaleType` with e.g. `"centerCrop"` (which *usually* is the best choice for backgrounds).

Answer (score 1):

Try with replacing **android:src** property with **android:background** in your **ImageView** layout. I think that will solve your issue. If it is still causing the issue then please let me know.